# Write Int array to Stream in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, binary, stream

what's the best way to write the binary representation of an int array (`Int32[]`) to a `Stream`?

`Stream.Write` only accepts `byte[]` as source and I would like to avoid converting/copying the array to an `byte[]` (array but instead streaming directly from the 'original location').

In a more system-oriented language (a.k.a. C++) I would simply cast the int array to a `byte*` but as far as I understood this isn't possible with C# (and moreover, casting `byte*` to `byte[]` wouldn't work out either way)

Thanks

Martin

PS: Actually, I would also like to stream single `int` values. Does using `BinaryConverter.GetBytes()` create a new byte array? In this case I extend my question to how to efficiently stream single `int` values ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) wrapping your output stream, and call [`Write(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w.aspx) for each of your `int` values. If that doesn't use the right endianness for you, you could use `EndianBinaryWriter` from my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) library.

I don't know of anything built-in to do this more efficiently... I'd hope that the buffering within the stream would take care of it for the most part.

Comment: In a very unscientific test the buffer seems to handle looping over the array and calling Write(int) on each value efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: Do be careful; stream wrappers like `BinaryWriter` tend to close the stream when they're done with it... not handy if you want to pass the stream with its written contents on to something else to handle stuff like writing it.

Comment: @Nyerguds: `BinaryWriter` provides an option of leaving the stream open for precisely this reason. I haven't included details of that in the answer as the question didn't indicate that it was necessary.

Comment: I know, I just thought it was worth at least adding as comment because I ran into that issue again today... on an old 3.5 project, too, where that option isn't available. Ah well, dispose-blocking wrapper class it is.

Answer (score 3):

System.Array and System.Int32 both have the SerializableAttribute and so both support default serialization in a retrievable format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

There is sample code for Binary output and readback here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904194(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I since need to control exactly which bytes are written, I'll go with `BinaryWriter`.